# Condition number of a diagonal matrix with norm not induced by an inner product

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, condition-number

I am trying to prove the following:

> For any diagonal matrix $D = \mbox{diag}(d_i)$, we have $$\mbox{cond}(D)=\frac{\max|d_i|}{\min|d_i|}$$ The matrix norm is a norm induced by a vector norm, i.e., $$\|A\| := \max_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|$$ for any vector norm $\|\cdot\|$.

If the vector norm in the problem is induced by an inner product, I have managed to prove the above. Is it also true for **any** vector norm?

Comment: It’s not true e.g. for the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Thank you, I meant for matrix norms induced by vector norms. I will edit my question

Comment: Ok. It is certainly true for standard $p$-norms but does not need to be true for weighted ones. So the answer is still no :-)

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Take any invertible matrix $S$ and define a new norm $\|x\|_S:=\|Sx\|$. The induced matrix norm is $\|A\|_S=\|SAS^{-1}\|$. So if this formula were true then for any diagonalizable matrix (and by continuity for *every* invertible matrix) we would have $cond(A)$ equal to the ratio of the largest and the smallest eigenvalue. And that is certainly false, e.g. for the max norm.

Comment: @Conifold That is a nice source of examples but I’m not sure by the eigenvalue argument. The condition number is not equal to the ratio of eigenvalues already for the spectral norm.

Comment: @Conifold I'm not sure I understand your example. Could you explain a bit more?